# asp.NET MVC Identity login page - Where is this pointing to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I just started some tutorials on MVC (I'm an old .net framework programmer).

In the pre-configured **ASP.NET MVC Web App** setup (in Visual Studio 2019), I'm trying to find where the actual Login page is (the HTML). I assume this is pre-built into Microsoft Identity. Is there any way to change this login form?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are scaffolded items Microsoft generated for you for using identity users. You have to follow some steps to add them to your project.

1. Press the right mouse button on your project.
2. Press Add
3. Add a new Scaffolded item
4. Select the identity options and click add.
5. Now you can a list of pages. You can select all the pages you want to use in your project. Select the data context dropdown value. The default value will generate an Application db context class for you and install the necessary packages.

Now you can see you have some extra files in your project/Areas/Identity/Pages folder. you will also find a folder named 'data' that implement Applicationdb context.